Toilet Tank overflow from flusher
There has been water overflowing from the tank on my toilet. The water comes out as a small stream coming out from the flusher handle. I have noticed that this tends to happen if the toilet has not been used for more that 12 hours.
I have currently put a small metal bowl on the floor near where the spill is so that it doesn't really flood the basement. If not used for 12 hours, by the time I would notice it, there is about 500ml of clear liquid in the metal bowl.
I tend to wait after the flush has finished to hear if there is any additional air circulating in the pipes or in the tank.
If I happen to continue to use the toilet every few hours, I do not have an overflow.
The apartment I am in has a Korky Quiet fill toilet valve, and the refill tube tends to bend to go into the tube in my toilet.

A picture inside the tank of the toilet would help greatly.  Have you flushed the toilet with the lid off the tank to see what is going on?

It sounds as if the water level in the tank rises to the hole for the flush handle  and seeps out there.  It should not go that high...so knowing what is causing the water level to be high would require looking INSIDE the tank..

how would a small bowl prevent the basement flooding?

There should be an overflow tube inside the tank, with an open end significantly LOWER than the hole for the handle. This makes it impossible for the water level in the tank to rise any higher than that tube, because the water overflows into the bowl below. The normal water level in the tank should be set about 1" BELOW the end of the overflow tube.

You pointed out what SHOULD be in the tank.  With the issues the OP has it is doubtful they have the situation you described.  That is why we need pictures of what is actually in the tank. Otherwise everything is speculation.

The OP is describing it: "and the refill tube tends to bend to go into the tube in my toilet."

@DelphicOracle, The description does not tell us how high the refill tube is, or if the fill valve is set wrong, or if there is a leak squirting water at the flush handle.  This problem could be easily remedied if the OP would post a clear pic of what is inside the tank.   Many of us know how it SHOULD work, but the unit is not working as it should.

Fill valves fail after a while and must be replaced.
